# $N/C$ contains $\operatorname{GL}_{2}(2)$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, classical-groups

In $G = \operatorname{PGL}_{4}(\mathbb{C})$, a subgroup $E = <a,b,c,d>$ where $$a =\Delta 
(\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix})_{2}, b =\Delta 
(\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix})_{2},$$ $$c =\begin{pmatrix}
I_{2} & 0\\
0 & -I_{2}
\end{pmatrix},d =\begin{pmatrix}
0 & I_{2}\\
I_{2} & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$ Here $\Delta(M)_{n}$ means $n$-copies of a matrix $M$ embedded diagonally.

$C_{G}(E)=E$ and $N_{G}(E)/C_{G}(E)=\operatorname{Sp}(4,2).$

Take $A=<a,c>$. I wish to show $\operatorname{GL}(2,2)\leqslant N_{G}(A)/C_{G}(A).$ (It's in fact $\cong$)

Proof. $N_{G}(E)/C_{G}(E)=\operatorname{Sp}(4,2)$ has a subgroup $\operatorname{GL}(2,2)$ stabilizing $A$. Let $g_{i}$ be the generators of $\operatorname{GL}(2,2)$ for $i = 1 ... k$. Thus
$$  \cup_{i=1}^{k} C_{G}(E)g_{i} \subseteq N_{G}(A).$$
Because $\operatorname{GL}(2,2)$ acts faithfully on $A$, none of $C_{G}(E)g_{i}$ is in $C_{G}(A).$ Thus,
$$  \cup_{i=1}^{k} C_{G}(A)g_{i} \subseteq N_{G}(A)$$ and
$\operatorname{GL}(2,2)\leqslant N_{G}(A)/C_{G}(A).$

$\Box$

I realized that the last inclusion doesn't guarantee the implication of the conclusion as the $g_{i}$'s might satisfy some additional relations because $C_{G}(E)\leqslant C_{G}(A)$. Not sure how to fine-tune this..

Comment: Perhaps you should say what $\Delta(\ldots)_2$ means.

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Comment: I think it is easier to do this directly and just write down a subgroup of $N_G(A)$ isomorphic to ${\rm GL}(2,2)$ that acts faithfully on $A$ and hence intersects $C_G(A)$ trivially. Note that $\langle a,c \rangle$ is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$, and you can choose the subgroup to consist of permutation matrices.

Comment: @DerekHolt  Would you please elaborate more on how to choose the permutation matrices ? I hope to try generalizing this. Thx.